# Issue between mongodb and EventEmitter

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having a weird issue between node-mongodb-native and EventEmitter.

I've reduced the problem to this code:

```
var mongodb = require( 'mongodb' ),
    Server = mongodb.Server,
    Db = mongodb.Db,
    events = require( 'events' ).EventEmitter.prototype;

// Create a mongo client object
var client = new Db( 'tartempion',
    new Server(
        '127.0.0.1',
        27017
    )
);

// Open the connection
client.open( function( err, db ) {
    if ( err ) throw err;
    database = db;
    console.log( 'Database driver loaded.' );
    events.emit( 'hi' );
});

// If I comment this out, I don't get the error anymore
// and the "Database driver loaded." log is displayed.
events.on( 'hi', function() {
    console.log( 'hey man' );
});
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
net.js:140
    // Uncomment the following lines after libuv backend is stable and API
      ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I thought this may be related to events in a callback, but this code works:

```
events.on( 'hi', function() {
    console.log( 'hey man' );
});

f( function() {
    events.emit( 'hi' );
});

function f( callback ) {
    callback();
}
```

So... I'm not seeing where the issue is.

Just FYI, I cross posted this on the node-mongodb-native [issue queue](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/issues/680).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to define `events` as an instance of `EventEmitter` rather than just a reference to the `EventEmitter.prototype` object:

```
var ...,
    EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
    events = new EventEmitter;
```

Or as an object that inherits from `EventEmitter.prototype`:

```
var ...,
    events = Object.create(require('events').EventEmitter.prototype);
```

You only get one `EventEmitter.prototype` per run of `node.exe` (since the result of `require('events')` is cached), so using it as an instance may modify every actual instances used throughout the core Node APIs and by 3rd-party modules like `mongodb`.

---

As [Brandon suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991781/issue-between-mongodb-and-eventemitter/11993430#comment15995002_11993430), if you need to access the instance in 2 modules, define it in a 3rd module:

```
// emitter.js
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
module.exports = new EventEmitter;
```

```
var ...,
    events = require('./emitter');
```

Comment: Well, the thing is, I want to use this event in two different files, so I can't instantiate an object, since it won't be the same object in both files. That's why I thought of using the prototype of EventEmitter. However, why do I *need* to instantiate it if it works without instantiating it? (See examples).

Comment: Other libraries or modules within the MongoDB package or its dependencies may be depending on EventEmitter, and my guess is they're running into issues because you are clobbering its prototype by attaching event handlers and such. If you need to use the same object in multiple files, [make a module](http://nodecasts.net/episodes/3-modules), don't use the prototype.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine If you mean your 2nd snippet, that works without creating an instance because you're not using any other instances -- such as `mongodb.Db`, [which inherits from `EventEmitter`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/V1.0.2/lib/mongodb/db.js#L217).

Comment: Oh, thanks for the info! I'm accepting your answer for the mention of this conflict :)

Answer (score 3):

If you say:

```
events = require( 'events' ).EventEmitter.prototype;
event.on('foo');
```

You are asking for trouble because then EVERY event object will get this binding (because you are writing it to the base prototype for all events)...

It's much better (as Jonathon says) to instantiate a new object upon which to bind your events...

sharedEventEmitter.js

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();
module.exports = eventEmitter;
```

Now from the rest of your project - you can treat this like a singleton - one object that will emit events to anything listening - each time you require('sharedEventEmitter') you get the same instance back (it's a singleton):

a.js

```
var sharedEvents = require('./sharedEventEmitter');
sharedEvents.on('foo', function(st){
  console.log(st);
})
```

b.js

```
var sharedEvents = require('./sharedEventEmitter');
sharedEvents.emit('hello from another file');
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, this is what I went for finally. Just FYI, the emitted event doesn't have any listener in your example :p.